# Doctrine 2 DQL - Select rows where a many-to-many field is empty?

Tags: php, doctrine, dql

I have two classes in this example - DeliveryMethod and Country. They have a many-to-many relationship with each other.

What I want to do is select all DeliveryMethods that do not have any Countries mapped to them.

I can do the opposite, that is select all delivery methods that have at least one country -

```
SELECT m FROM DeliveryMethod m JOIN m.countries
```

But I can't figure out how to do select where the countries field is empty. In plain SQL I would do the following (deliverymethod_country is the linking table):

```
SELECT m.* FROM deliverymethods m
LEFT JOIN deliverymethod_country dc ON dc.deliverymethod_id = m.id
WHERE dc.deliverymethod_id IS NULL
```

However any DQL equivalent of this doesn't work, for example:

```
SELECT m FROM DeliveryMethod m LEFT JOIN m.countries WHERE m.countries IS NULL
```

Which gives me this error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 75: Error: Expected end of string, got 'm'
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What about this? Assuming `$qb` is your query builder instance

```
$qb->select('m')
   ->from('DeliveryMethods','m')
   ->leftJoin('m.countries','c')
   ->having('COUNT(c.id) = 0')
   ->groupBy('m.id');
```

This would give you the DeliveryMethods which is associated with countries and count of the associated countries is 0

Comment: Almost perfect, just needed to change ->join() to ->leftJoin() because otherwise it limits the query to methods that have at least one country and returns an empty result.

Comment: I am having a smiliar problem, maybe you can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387797/how-to-write-this-query-in-query-builder

Comment: @Broncha what about one-to-one relations?

Comment: @parisssss I guess the same should work in One-To-One as well. On second thought, if the left entity is the owning side, you can just use `$qb->expr()->isNull()`

Comment: @Broncha thanks!!it's just worked with `$qb->expr()->isNull()` :)

Comment: @Broncha brilliant been struggling with this for hours.

Comment: This isn’t working on my end. The other solution submitted by @flu works like a charm

Comment: using a having clause mean that the database have to retrieve the rows and then filter them this is counterproductive. You should use @flu 's solution.

Comment: As stated by @Bruno above, both for readability and performance the 'm.countries is empty' should be used.

Answer (score 84):

### Use Doctrine's `is empty`

It's specifically designed to check for empty associations:

```
$qb->select('m')->from('DeliveryMethods', 'm')->where('m.countries is empty')
```

See: [Doctrine 2 ORM Documentation: Doctrine Query Language](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-select-examples) (search for "is empty")

Comment: Best answer. I am looking for a way to use this within an `Expr` context, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41935897/how-to-use-doctrines-is-empty-within-an-expression

Comment: This should be the top answer.

Comment: Just one remark - if you are building the query with *join*, you must use *leftJoin*

Answer (score 16):

There is no need in joins and havings. Simply use `SIZE` function:

```
$qb->select('m')
   ->from('DeliveryMethods','m')
   ->where('SIZE(m.countries) = 0');
```

This will give you all methods without attached countries

Comment: the better answer, leaves out exceptions where you might need another query because of the 'having'. doctrine will figure out the best strategy, it will for example do an subselect if the relation isnt fetch-joined.

Answer (score 0):

Can't join NULL values, IIRC. Apologies for the typo on twitter, should have said "can't".