# How to use Doctrine's "is empty" within an Expression?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Related to [this answer on how to check for the (non)existance of related entities using Doctrine's `is empty` query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39998912/2564552), I try to use this within a Doctrine Expression, but the [`Expr` Class](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class) has no documented way to use `is empty`. `isNull` doesn't work. So what I am looking for is an Expression like:

```
// filter for e with no relatedEntities
$qb->expr()->isEmpty('e.realatedEntities');
// filter for e with relatedEntities
$qb->expr()->isNotEmpty('e.realatedEntities');
```

So any ideas on this?

Doctrine's `SIZE` also has also no equivalent in the `Expr`-Class. Am I missing something? For now, I manipulate the query object instead of returning an expression (in Lexik form filter bindle for Symfony), but this is only a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the operands of the [comparison expressions](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.5/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Expr/Comparison.php) are DQL expressions themselves you can write:

```
$qb->expr()->gt('size(e.relatedEntities)', 0)
```

They get converted to a DQL string in the expression's `__toString()` method which in this case is defined as:

```
$this->leftExpr . ' ' . $this->operator . ' ' . $this->rightExpr;
```

So this should produce:

```
"size(e.relatiedEntities) > 0"
```

Further reading:

As `$qb->expr()` does nothing more than return `Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr` objects you can take a look into the classes of that namespace if you want some information about building more sophisticated expressions.